# How can I handle errors using ActionBuilder, and Action composition?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have two Actions:

```scala
object ErrorHandler extends
    ActionBuilder[Request]{
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    try {
      block(request)
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => Future.successful{
        InternalServerError(
          Json.obj(
            "status" -> JsString("error")
          )
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And another action:

```scala
object WithFieldAction extends
    ActionBuilder[WithFieldRequest] with ActionTransformer[Request, WithFieldRequest] {

  val FIELD = "field"

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]) = Future.successful {
    new WithFieldRequest(request.getQueryString(FIELD), request)
  }
}
```

I combine this actions:

```scala
def index = (ErrorHandler andThen WithFieldAction) { implicit request =>
  1 / 0
}
```

But `ErrorHandler` doesn't catch the exception and I see the default error page. How can I fix it? (I can't use the Global error handler because I want to have different handlers for different groups of endpoints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the exception is thrown within the `Future` and held. That means that when you call `block(request)`, it's just going to return a `Future[Result]` that wraps the eventual exception (a failed `Future`). The `Future` should never let the exception escape it, so wrapping in try/catch won't do anything.

Instead, you need to `recover` the `Future`.

```
def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
  block(request) recover { ex: Throwable =>
    InternalServerError(
      Json.obj(
        "status" -> JsString("error")
      )
    )
  }
}
```

`recover` accepts a `PartialFunction[Throwable, ?]`, so you can be as fine-grained about the exceptions you handle as you want. For example, you could recover only `java.lang.ArithmeticException`, and let all other failures propagate to Play's error handling if you wish.